# How to eliminate data.name from t.test output

Tags: r

I did this `t.test` (in this case, I'll use the `iris` dataset):

```r
> t.test(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width)

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  iris$Sepal.Length and iris$Sepal.Width
t = 36.463, df = 225.68, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 2.63544 2.93656
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 5.843333  3.057333
```

However, I'd like to erase the call (the `t.test` output is a list, and I want to remove the column `data.name`, as mentioned in the R Documentation or by digging into it).

I tried doing two things (that made some sense to me); I tried doing it using the index (which completely dismanteled the `t.test` and instead of this nice text gave a an actual list)

```
> result <- t.test(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width)
> result$data.name <-  ""
> result

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  
t = 36.463, df = 225.68, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 2.63544 2.93656
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 5.843333  3.057333
```

Almost... This is almost what I want, but there's still that `data:`  in there. If I do `NA` instead, it just says `data: NA` instead.

How can I remove that line? Is there even a way?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new `print.htest` function. First, the whole function can be found by calling `getS3method("print", "htest")`. Then remove the line that you do not want like this:

```r
print.htest <- function (x, digits = getOption("digits"), prefix = "\t", ...) 
{
    cat("\n")
    cat(strwrap(x$method, prefix = prefix), sep = "\n")
    cat("\n")
    ####
    # the line you do not want!
    #cat("data:  ", x$data.name, "\n", sep = "")
    ####
    out <- character()
    if (!is.null(x$statistic)) 
        out <- c(out, paste(names(x$statistic), "=", format(x$statistic, 
            digits = max(1L, digits - 2L))))
    if (!is.null(x$parameter)) 
        out <- c(out, paste(names(x$parameter), "=", format(x$parameter, 
            digits = max(1L, digits - 2L))))
    if (!is.null(x$p.value)) {
        fp <- format.pval(x$p.value, digits = max(1L, digits - 
            3L))
        out <- c(out, paste("p-value", if (substr(fp, 1L, 1L) == 
            "<") fp else paste("=", fp)))
    }
    cat(strwrap(paste(out, collapse = ", ")), sep = "\n")
    if (!is.null(x$alternative)) {
        cat("alternative hypothesis: ")
        if (!is.null(x$null.value)) {
            if (length(x$null.value) == 1L) {
                alt.char <- switch(x$alternative, two.sided = "not equal to", 
                  less = "less than", greater = "greater than")
                cat("true ", names(x$null.value), " is ", alt.char, 
                  " ", x$null.value, "\n", sep = "")
            }
            else {
                cat(x$alternative, "\nnull values:\n", sep = "")
                print(x$null.value, digits = digits, ...)
            }
        }
        else cat(x$alternative, "\n", sep = "")
    }
    if (!is.null(x$conf.int)) {
        cat(format(100 * attr(x$conf.int, "conf.level")), " percent confidence interval:\n", 
            " ", paste(format(x$conf.int[1:2], digits = digits), 
                collapse = " "), "\n", sep = "")
    }
    if (!is.null(x$estimate)) {
        cat("sample estimates:\n")
        print(x$estimate, digits = digits, ...)
    }
    cat("\n")
    invisible(x)
}
```

Having assigned this in the global environment, I now get:

```r
t.test(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width)
#R> 
#R>     Welch Two Sample t-test
#R> 
#R> t = 36.463, df = 225.68, p-value < 2.2e-16
#R> alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
#R> 95 percent confidence interval:
#R>  2.63544 2.93656
#R> sample estimates:
#R> mean of x mean of y 
#R>  5.843333  3.057333
```

Comment: hmmm i would write a new function..in any case, unusual request i guess.

Comment: There might be used assignInNamespace . Temporary overwrite the function and on.exit return to original one.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do:

```
cat("print.htest<-",
    paste(grep("data|<environment",capture.output(getS3method("print", "htest")), 
               invert = TRUE, value = TRUE), collapse = "\n"), file="temp.R")
source("temp.R")

result <- t.test(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width)

    Welch Two Sample t-test

t = 36.463, df = 225.68, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 2.63544 2.93656
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 5.843333  3.057333
```

To revert  it to the normal case, just do `rm(print.htest)`. It is better to have the change in the global environment rather than changing the function in the namespace through lock/unlockbinding the namespace